# Using Case Statements with a Cross Apply and Select Top

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below code, I want the first line of the Select Top to look like this if the hour of the enddate is equal to 0.

```
SELECT TOP ( ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.startdatetime, A.enddatetime) + 1))
```

But I want it to look like this if the hour of the enddate is not equal to 0.

```
SELECT TOP ( ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.startdatetime, A.enddatetime)))
```

But, I'm struggling to determine how you incorporate a case statement into this, since it would need to sit within the cross apply.

```
 --Create my temporary table
    SELECT * into #Temporary
    FROM dbo.Census
    WHERE year(startdatetime) >= 2018
    ORDER BY startdatetime, pt_id

    --Use the Cross Apply to split out every day into every hour
    SELECT
    Date = CAST(D AS DATE)
    ,Hour = DATEPART(HOUR, D)
    ,A.pt_id
    ,cendate
    ,A.[locationid]
    ,A.[room-bed]
    ,startdatetime
    ,enddatetime
    ,minutes
    ,MyStartMinutes = 0
    ,MyEndMinutes = 0
    INTO #Temporary2
    FROM #Temporary A
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP ( ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.startdatetime, A.enddatetime) + 1))
        D = DATEADD(HOUR, -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )), A.startdatetime)
    FROM master..spt_values n1
        ,master..spt_values n2
    ) B



 Sample Data
 Date       pt_id   cendate    loc  startdate       enddate          minutes
 10/9/2018  100     10/2/2018   A   10/1/2018 22:00 10/2/2018 0:35   155
 10/10/2018 100     10/2/2018   B   10/2/2018 0:35  10/2/2018 23:00  1345


 It should result in: 

 Date        Hour  loc     pt_id      (Start Time)       (End Time)
 10/9/2018   22    A      100        10/9/2018 22:00     10/9/2018 23:00
 10/9/2018   23    A      100        10/9/2018 23:00     10/10/2018 0:00
 10/10/2018  0     A      100        10/10/2018 0:00     10/10/2018 0:35
 10/10/2018  0     B      100        10/10/2018 0:35     10/10/2018 1:00
```

Comment: This looks like T-SQL so I'm guessing you are working with Sql Server.
Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Add proper tag to your question.  `SQL` is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.

Comment: You could probably just do this easier by using a regular numbers table from 0 to 23.

Comment: I think you can just use an `iif()` function call.  Without your data to work against, I'd suggest `SELECT TOP ( ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.startdatetime, A.enddatetime) + iif(datepart(hour, A.enddatetime)=0, 1, 0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
SELECT TOP ( ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.startdatetime, A.enddatetime) + 1))
```

With this:

```
SELECT TOP (ABS(DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.startdatetime, A.enddatetime) + (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, A.enddatetime) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works great.  The only problem I'm facing now is that when I have a patient who moves units between midnight and 1 a.m., I'm losing the first part.  I added example data above.

Comment: You just need to cast which ever date you are working with to the correct format. Check out some of the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: There may be a much easier, less error prone, way to accomplish what ever you are trying to do. If you still have issues, try describing the source tables and the results you expect see a little bit more.